# TCPDF ERROR: in Joomla vik rental car

Tags: php, curl, joomla, tcpdf

I am using Vik rental car for joomla side. So, when i click any payment method , i got this error,

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /kunden/homepages/24/d419082057/htdocs/Exclusive/homepages/24/d419082057/htdocs/Exclusive/administrator/components/com_vikrentcar/resources/logo.png
```

So i changed lib.vikrentalcar.php ,Line no 1968: 
Actual code is :

`$tlogo = !empty($tlogo) ? str_replace(JURI::root().'administrator', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, $tlogo) : "";`

to

`$tlogo = !empty($tlogo) ? str_replace(JURI::root().'administrator', '/htdocs/Exclusive/administrator', $tlogo) : "";`

But this doesn't work.. 
Please , Anyone have a insights?

Comment: I might be blind but the only differences I see in what you have changed is you have added more spaces?. TCPDF is an open source class and the answer is given to you. The image that has been requested to be added into the PDF does not exist or is blocked by directory permissions.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake . i updated  this post. @Zanderwar

Comment: `echo JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR;` to ensure it's defined. If it is as expected, are you getting any additional error than what you have already provided?

Comment: if i echo this in template , i got this `/homepages/24/d419082057/htdocs/Exclusive/administrator`

But if i add this to lib.vikrentalcar.php, then all website is blank.

Comment: Can you confirm via FTP or otherwise that the path exists? If so, try adding the full path (e.g `http://www.example.com/homepages/24/d419082057/htdocs/Exclusive/administrator`) - Also please check Apache/PHP error logs

Comment: If i try to reach this by typing in url bar , then i get this message:
`ERROR 404: ARCHIVO NO ENCONTRADO

El documento solicitado no ha sido encontrado.`

I email to Vik rent car , They gave me 2 suggestion .I tried both. 1st suggestion regarding hosting . and they told me, they can't . 
You can see this reply.. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pySr4ifr05p4Fh1bsverjHDBOAaTjiFnq6SOi4RMTC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, my experience in Joomla doesn't extend as far as missing directories. Generally I'd recommend a reinstall.

Comment: Thanks . I think this is for PHP cURL . But not sure. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

after adding this 
`$tlogo = !empty($tlogo) ? str_replace(JURI::root().'./administrator', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, $tlogo) : "";`

Now its works. 
Only difference is `'./administrator'`